Trouble setting multiple local docker containers using traefik to run under a custom base domain name and port 80
I have been trying to setup traefik and Docker Desktop to run different containers pointing to the same base custom domain name on port 80 as follows:

docker container "content" runs against http://dev.mydomain.com/docs/contents/swagger
docker container "basket" runs against http://dev.mydomain.com/docs/baskets/swagger

I have already changed my local hosts file to point:
dev.mydomain.com 127.0.0.0
My traefik script looks thus (note: i am expecting to expose port 8080 on the container, hence why i am changing traefik dashboard to 8099):
docker run -d --name traefik \
  --network dev-mobile \
  --publish 80:8080 --publish 8099:8099 \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  traefik:v2.10 --api.insecure=true --providers.docker=true --entrypoints.dev-mobile.address=:8080 --entrypoints.traefik.address=:8099

I have a docker file as follows in Dockerfile.Basket (similar setup for other containers):
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
ARG VERSION
ENV DD_VERSION=${VERSION}
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./<my files> .
EXPOSE 8080
USER app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "<my dll entrypoint>"]

Docker build
docker build -t basket_image -f ./local-docker/Dockerfile.Basket .

Docker run
docker run -d --name basket \
  --network dev-mobile \
  -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Local \
  --label "traefik.enable=true" \
  --label "traefik.http.routers.basket.rule=Host(`dev.mydomain.com`)" \
  --label "traefik.http.services.basket.loadbalancer.server.port=80" \
  basket_image

I do the same setup for other containers for the docker file, docker build and docker run setup. Trying to load http://dev.mydomain.com/docs/baskets/swagger gives me a 404 page not found. However, if I specify a port number e.g -p 8090:8080 and set "traefik.http.services.basket.loadbalancer.server.port=8090", http://dev.mydomain.com:8090/docs/baskets/swagger with the 8090 port number works as expected. What I am doing wrong that i cannot use port 80?

I don't know if it differs on windows/Microsoft-images but on unix docker your user app won't be able to bind port 80 in the container as it's a privileged port (<1024)

Thanks micke, I have managed to solve it actually. If anyone else have this issue in future, note that traefik is unable to find the routes properly if you don't specify very "specific" routes to route to. In my case, I solved it by adding additional "PathPrefix" and "StripPrefix" labels for each of my container services, then, dev.mydomain.com was able to resolve each service under port 80!

Great. You might wanna add and accept your own answer with a more thorough explanation of what do did.
